# How do I access the inner values of my custom Wagtail block?

Tags: django, wagtail

I've created a custom block with nested blocks. How do I access the fields in the inner block? For example, I want to display the icon, title, and description.

I have tried several variations of this:

```
{% for block in value %}
   {% if block.block_type == 'features' %}
      {% for subblock in block.value %}
          {{ subblock.value.title }}
```

This is my block definition:

```
class Features_1_Block(blocks.StructBlock):
    title = blocks.CharBlock()
    description = blocks.TextBlock(required=False)
    features = blocks.ListBlock(
        blocks.StructBlock([
            ('icon', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('title', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('description', blocks.TextBlock())
        ])
    )

    class Meta:
        template = 'streamfield_blocks/features_1.html'
```

Currently there is no output.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out my problem, which was embarrassingly simple.

```
{% for block in value.features %}
     {{ block.title }}
{% endfor %}
```